# Error: retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@94952f

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

I want to get information using retrofit2
However, it is not possible due to the first error. How to solve this
this error is not infomation,,,,,

```css
data class Beers(


    val id : String,
    val name : String,
    val ph : Int,
    val first_brewed : String
)
```

```html
     val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(BeerService::class.java)


        service.getBeers().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Beers>>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Beers>>, response: Response<List<Beers>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val body = response.body()
                    binding.tvRe.text = body.toString()
                   Log.d("Response :", response?.body().toString())
//                    body?.let {
//
//                    }
//                Log.d("Response :", response?.body().toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Beers>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Error", call.toString())
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the data class
val ph : Int  --> val ph : Float